# How to change the border color in DB-Visualizer?

Tags: sql-server, database, dbvisualizer

I am using DB-Visualizer 9.2.10 and I want to change the border color of the editor but I don't see any border option to change. Below image shows the options colors and borders but in my pro version I don't see this option. Is there any other way to accomplish the same.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to change the border by going to Tools -> Properties.

You can either select one of the predefined styles or specify a small image file to use for the border.

You should also be able to change it by going to Database -> Connections